# React Router en producción

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

Tengo un proyecto en React.

Para las rutas uso **react-router-dom 5.0.1**. El problema surge cuando pongo en producción React y refresco la página y da error **Not Found**.

Siempre que me muevo a otra ruta http://miweb.com/ruta y refresco, da ese error. Para desarrollo uso webpack server y todo bien, pero ¿y en producción?

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar el escenario con más detalle? ¿Qué rutas carga bien y qué rutas muestran un 404?

Comment: En producción que servidor web estás usando? Hay que especificar que todo el tráfico se redireccioné a '/'

Answer (score 2):

No es estrictamente necesario hacer Server side render. Lo único que necesitas es enrutar las peticiones de todas las URL que no apuntan a un recurso físico (archivo, carpeta), al script que funciona como front_controller.

Realmente depende de que servidor web estés utilizando, si eres más específico, esta respuesta puede serlo también.

- [Ejemplo con PHP](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/web_servers.html)
- si tu aplicación corre con express necesitas una ruta que atienda todas las URL no explícitamente enrutadas a otros controladores.
- Si tu webapp está en github pages e index.html es el script donde corre tu router de React, duplica su código en un 404.html

Answer (score 0):

He estado investigando aún más y al parecer hace falta un que react haga server side rendering para mantener la rutas al refrescar o al entrar directamente con una ruta específica.

Esto ocurre porque ahora mismo el build que genera react es una SPA y hace falta primer pasar por el index para cargar toda la lógica de enrutamiento.